# Why is there isn't a Theory of everything after decades of research?

Tags: quantum-gravity, theory-of-everything

Why isnt there a theory of everything after decades of research by the best minds of the world. Is it because that general relativity and quantum mechanics are so different in their ideals

Comment: We already have plenty of "unified field theories", both with and without gravity. It's just that nobody knows how to test them!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153937/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Maybe the question is a duplicate, but the answers can now be different.